# Algorithms for automatic PID tuning?

Tags: pid-controller

[I am given to understand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#PID_tuning_software) that there exists software for tuning PID controllers. I haven't had much luck finding references, though. Pros/cons for algorithms, and references for them?

**ADDED**: I'm specifically looking for a description (scholarly or otherwise) of how automatic tuning software does its job; not references to automatic tuning software or packages. My use case is not "I have a PID control loop I want to automatically tune" but rather, "I wish to write a piece of software to automatically tune PID control loops for particular pieces of hardware, so that others do not have to do the job manually."

Comment: The reference states that this is often implemented in hardware. Are there any chips that incorporate PID tuning?

Comment: PID is usually implemented in software.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=710876) paper discusses a method for automatic tuning, that at least [this](http://www.mstarlabs.com/control/selftune.html) company seems to use for their automatic online self-tuning controller.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab (expensive) and Scilab (free) offer PID modeling and can be used for tuning PID control systems. [Here](http://www.proceedings2008.imcsit.org/pliks/157.pdf) is an example using Scilab.